# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I get this error in the javascript console of a google chrome extension that I'm making and I don't know why, can someone help me?
Here are my scripts:

**popup.js**

```
function urlReduce(href){
    href = href.replace(href.substring(href.indexOf(location.pathname), href.length), "");
    href = href.replace("http://", "").replace("www.", "");
    return href;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    var hosts = ["novamov.com", "videoweed.es", "vidspot.net", "allmyvideos.net", "streamcloud.eu", "magnovideo.com", "played.to", "vk.com", "moevideos.net", "youtube.com", "videomega.tv", "movshare.net"];
    var url = urlReduce(message.url);
    var found = $.inArray(url, hosts) > -1;
    if (found) {
    alert("sending msg");
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method:'getInfo'}, function(response){
            var response_array = response.split(",");
            var title = response_array[0];
            var serie = response_array[1];
            var number = response_array[2];
            var url = response_array[3];            
        });


        $("#serie").html(serie);
        $("#url").html(url);
        $("#number").html(number);
        $("#title").html(title);
    }
}
```

**And here the head from popup.html**

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second function has a callback and is not properly closed

```
function urlReduce(href) {
    href = href.replace(href.substring(href.indexOf(location.pathname), href.length), "");
    href = href.replace("http://", "").replace("www.", "");
    return href;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    var hosts = ["novamov.com", "videoweed.es", "vidspot.net", "allmyvideos.net", "streamcloud.eu", "magnovideo.com", "played.to", "vk.com", "moevideos.net", "youtube.com", "videomega.tv", "movshare.net"];
    var url = urlReduce(message.url);
    var found = $.inArray(url, hosts) > -1;
    if (found) {
        alert("sending msg");
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            method: 'getInfo'
        }, function (response) {
            var response_array = response.split(",");
            var title = response_array[0];
            var serie = response_array[1];
            var number = response_array[2];
            var url = response_array[3];
        });


        $("#serie").html(serie);
        $("#url").html(url);
        $("#number").html(number);
        $("#title").html(title);
    }
}); // close it properly
```

The browser console should tell you where the error is, at least mine does.